# PHP Javascript HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, database

I'm having trouble finding my exact question so I'll post it here. I'm working with an oracle database and I'm linking it to an HTML website via javascript and php. I got the php file to display properly. Essentially what's supposed to happen is I have 4 button, each one generates a specific query and displays the results in a new html page. It's a movie database, so one of our queries is Budgets vs. Genre. It works the way I have it, but it doesn't generate it via the html file, it displays the PHP file. My goal is to retrieve the output of the PHP file via javascript and set it to the HTML file for output. I'm new to php and javascript working together, so maybe someone can tell me what's happening here and what needs to be changed for it to work properly. I got the javascript code from oracles website for connecting a database to a website.

Here's my PHP first:

```
<?php

        // Connect to the database=
        $c = oci_connect ("user101", "pass101", "localhost:1521/XE");

        // Define the query.
        $q = 'SELECT distinct m.title, f.budget FROM movies m, finance f WHERE m.imdb_id = f.imdb_id AND  budget > 100000000 ORDER BY budget DESC';


        // Parse the query.
        $s = oci_parse($c, $q);

        $didbv = 60;
        oci_bind_by_name($s, ':budget', $budget);
        oci_bind_by_name($s, ':title', $title);

        // Execute the query.
        oci_execute($s);

        $i = 1;
        print '<table border="1"><tr><th>Rank</th><th>Title</th><th>Budget</th>';
        while (($row = oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_ASSOC)) != false) {
        $table[i++] = array("title" => $row['TITLE'], 'budget' => $row['BUDGET']);
        }
        oci_free_statement($s);

        // Close the connection.
        oci_close($c);
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($table);

?>
```

and here's my javascript :

```
    $(function() {
  $("button#genBudg").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("ajaxCopy.php", function(data) {
      var reportTable = $("<table>", {
        border: 1
      });
      reportTable.append("<thead><th>Rank</th><th>Title</th><th>Budget</th></thead><tbody></tbody>");
      $.each(data, function(k, v) {
        reportTable.find("tbody").append("<tr><td>" + k + "</td><td>" + v.title + "</td><td>" + v.budget + "</td></tr>");
      });
      $("#bud_gro").append(reportTable);
        window.location.replace("generate_report.html");
    });
  });
});
```

and here's my html:
(select_report.html)

```
<html lang ="en">
<head>
  <title>Movie Analysis</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="movies.CSS">

</head>
<body>

  <h2>Reports</h2>
  <div class="input_options">
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="option" style="padding:10px 30px" id="genBudg">Genre vs Budget</button>
      <button type="button" class="option" style="padding:10px 30px">Rating vs Budget</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="option" style="padding:10px 30px">Budget vs Gross</button>
    <button type="button" class="option" style="padding:10px 30px">Actor vs Rating</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src ="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
  <script src="movies.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

(generate_report.html)

```
<html lang ="en">
<head>
  <title>Movie Analysis</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="movies.CSS">

</head>
<body>

  <h2>Name of report</h2>
  <div id = "bud_gro"></div>

  <script src="movies.js"></script>

  <script src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: another side note: my query isn't exactly what i want either, but this is just a test one to get it to display properly first.

Comment: well shoot. In the preview, my php showed up fine, but now that it shows, it looks all jumbled. Well if I need to resubmit php content, let me know. It may not be relevant though. Might just be the javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting edit, smcd :)

Comment: Would you consider passing JSON back to the AJAX and then building the table from the JSON Data?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed, it may be better to pass JSON data back to an AJAX call and build the table based on the results. This might look like this:

**PHP**

```
<?php
// Connect to the database= oci_connect ("user101", "pass101", "localhost:1521/XE");
// Define the query.
$q = 'SELECT distinct m.title, f.budget FROM movies m, finance f WHERE m.imdb_id = f.imdb_id AND  budget > 100000000 ORDER BY budget DESC';
// Parse the query.
$s = oci_parse($c, $q);
$didbv = 60;
oci_bind_by_name($s, ':budget', $budget);
oci_bind_by_name($s, ':title', $title);
// Execute the query.
oci_execute($s);
$i = 1;
$table = array();
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_ASSOC)) != false) {
    $table[i++] = array("title" => $row['TITLE'], "budget" => $row['BUDGET']);
}
oci_free_statement($s);
// Close the connection.
oci_close($c);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($table);
?>
```

You can then make use of a jQuery solution like so:

**HTML**

```
<button id="getReport">
  Get Report
</button>
<h2>Name of report</h2>
<p id="bud_gro"></p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("button#getReport").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("ajax.php", function(data) {
      var reportTable = $("<table>", {
        border: 1
      });
      reportTable.append("<thead><th>Rank</th><th>Title</th><th>Budget</th></thead><tbody></tbody>");
      $.each(data, function(k, v) {
        reportTable.find("tbody").append("<tr><td>" + k + "</td><td>" + v.title + "</td><td>" + v.budget + "</td></tr>");
      });
      $("#bud_gro").append(reportTable);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: it's not switching pages for me. I had to do some alterations. For instance, the button that queries the data is on a different page than where the data is to be shown. Therefore, after $(#bud_gro").append(reportTable); I added window.location.replace("generate_report.html). (bud_gro is a div in generate_report.html and getReport is the id of the button in select_report.html). Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @MikeP That is entirely unclear. You did not define this in your original post and I don't have a frame of reference from the example.

Comment: Ok it's updated, thanks guys for any advice or input.

Comment: Ok, something interesting. I checked if that function is being called by setting alert right after $("button#genBudg").click(function() { and nothing happens. Am I using this right, or do I still have to do onclick event in html? I even took away button and just used #genBudg and no change.

Comment: Ok i found out, it won't work unless I put it in the html file (not external .js). Having another issue i'm going to work on for a bit

Comment: Ok not sure what's going on here. A couple issues. First one is the jquery file that was included is throwing errors. 2nd one I still can't get it to flip pages. It will at the beginning of the function, but then nothing else happens. If I omit it for now or put it at the end, i get this error message

Comment: GET http://52.33.161.190/ajaxCopy.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
ajax @ jquery-1.4.4.js:6054
get @ jquery-1.4.4.js:5696
getJSON @ jquery-1.4.4.js:5710
(anonymous) @ select_report.html:29
handle @ jquery-1.4.4.js:2260
eventHandle @ jquery-1.4.4.js:1891

Comment: woo hoo no errors, had some syntax errors in php. And it's flipping pages but not displaying the results

Comment: Ok I know my problem why it won't display my results in a separate web page. It's because the id #bud_gro, is not accessible from the web page the button is on. Makes sense, but I can't get the button to work from my external js file. I need it to work from there so I can access both ids (genBudg and bud_gro). $(document).ready(function (){$(#genBudg).click(function)() { //do something} is not working. How do I handle a Jquery click event in external js file?

Comment: Your syntax is correct for the callback. I suspect that the problem is that the element does not exist on that page. How are you calling your JS File? Via `<script src="">`?

Comment: Also I do not see that button in either page. You do not need to wrap the code in a button `click` event unless you want to. When do you want the report to load?

Comment: And now that I review it more, I am not sure why you are using AJAX. Why not just call up the report data via PHP when the page loads?

Comment: yeah the js file is the movies.js specified in the script tag. The button is in the select_report.html with the id of genBudg and label as Genre vs budget. I want the report to load when i click the button and display it on another page. (click button, javascript sends request to php which runs the query, send it back to javascript, which spits the data onto a new html page).I wasn't sure how to do that without ajax. I found this technique on the oracle website. I'm still new to the backend web programming. Any suggestions for an easier way to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: Will look at out tomorrow

Comment: ugh everything I'm finding on why my button's not working in the external js file shows I'm doing it correct. Used $(document).ready before the function. Included the jquery file before my js file in the html file. Including those right before the end of the body tag. My index page works which has a validation function in the same js file. It's just the jquery one doesn't work. Only works when function is in script tags in the html file.

Comment: ok I figured it out, scrapped all that and found a way to do it without jquery. Just ajax, php, javascript, and html. I don't think jquery likes the click functions in an external file, lol